# Vertical And Horizontal range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there any jquery or maybe clear html5 range slider with one point that can go vertically and horizontally with two values? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't think that would be a range slider anymore. I found [this article](https://medium.com/@bantic/hand-coding-a-color-wheel-with-canvas-78256c9d7d43) that might be a helpful starting place.

Answer (score 0):

there are vertical or horizontal sliders, but a slider that does both, i don't know !

You could display 2 sliders at the bottom and the right, and then according the value of the 2 sliders it will move or show/hide the white point in the good place in your grid...

This library for instance will allow you to do this : http://rangeslider.js.org/